# C - Reading strings from a text file and arranging them by size

Tags: c, string, file, text, strlen

I want to read strings from a text file (one string/word per line) and then arrange them by size.

This is my code:

```
void readDic(char* file)
{
    FILE* fr; 
    fr=fopen(file, "rt"); // opening the text file
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char* word;
    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fr)!=NULL)
    {
        if(line[0]!='\n')
        {
            word = strtok(line, "\n"); //remove the newline from the string
            // do stuff with word
        }
    } 
    fclose(fr);
}
```

Although this code code runs, every string I read, except the last one, comes with a size of +1 than the one in the file.

For example, strlen of the string "hello" returns 6 if its anywhere except the last lineof the file.
If it is in the last line of the file strlen returns 5.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: more code required.  your example doesn't show how you are determining the length of the word.

Comment: If `strlen(x)`, where `x` ought to be "hello", returns 6, it might  be a good idea to check what that 6th character is. It might be something like an `\r`. (On further reflection: this may also be in the *first* position.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` does not read C strings.  It reads `chars` until encounters a `'\n'` ( or EOF condition, or IO error or the buffer is nearly filled).  Then it appends a `'\0'` to the buffer, making the buffer a C string.

After calling `fgets()`, good to check its return value - which this code did.  If `NULL`, an EOF condition or IO Error exist.  Otherwise the buffer contains a C string: 1) an array of `char`, 2) typically the last is a `'\n'` and 3) the appended `'\0'`.

The seemingly extra long result of `strlen(line)` is from the `'\n'`, which the last line of your text file does not have.

Suggestion to rid the maybe trailing `'\n'`:

```
size_t len = strlne(line);
if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') line[--len] = '\0';
```

---

Line endings vary between systems: `"\r\n"` and `"\n"` are popular, but `"\n\r"` and `"\r"` have occurred.  By opening the file as a *text* file `"rt"`, or more portable with `"r"`, the system's typical line ending is converted to `"\n"` as `fgets()` requests data from the underlying IO.  Given varieties amongst editors, it is possible that the text file that code is reading is using an *unexpected* line ending and is not translated as mentioned.